# Read directly from disk in DOS-BOX assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, dos, dosbox

I mount a folder from DOS-BOX on my computer `mount c c:\users\user\folder`. Then I delete a file in this folder and my task is to restore it. I have a byte mask of this file, so I just need to read data directly from disk in DOS-BOX to look for this mask. But how can I do it?

I use int 13h, but the result is 512 zero bytes, how can i find disk number, segment number if I'm on a mounted drive in DOS-BOX.

```
.model tiny
.code
org 100h

Begin:
  jmp Start

FName db 'myfile.txt',0
Count dw 512
position dw 0

Buf db 512 dup(?)

Start:
  
;-------------------------------------------------
;Read from disk to Buf
  
  push cx
  push dx
  push ds
  
  xor ax, ax
  mov ds, ax
  cld
  
  mov ah, 02h                 ; Function code for reading disk sectors
  mov al, 1                 ; Number of sectors to read
  mov ch, 0                   ; Cylinder number (starting from 0)
  mov cl, 2            ; Sector number (starting from 1)
  mov dh, 0                   ; Head number
  mov dl, 02h                 ; Drive number
  ;xor bx, bx
  ;mov es, bx
  lea bx, Buf             ; Buffer to store the sector data
  int 13h       
  
  
  pop ds
  pop dx
  pop cx
  
  
  
;--------------------------------------------------
;Write Buf to file  
  mov ah, 3ch
  mov cx, 1
  mov dx, offset FName
  int 21h
  
  
  
  mov bx, ax
  mov ah, 42h
  mov al, 0
  mov cx, 0
  mov dx, position
  int 21h
  
  
  
  MOV CX, Count
  MOV DX, offset Buf
  MOV ah, 40h
  int 21h
  
  
  mov ah, 3eh
  int 21h
  
;-----------------------------------------------------

Exit:
  mov ah, 4ch
  xor al, al
  int 21h
  


end Begin
```

Comment: DOSBox doesn't give you access to a host file system at the sector level.

Comment: Yeah, seems silly to try to experiment with disk level file system interaction on a virtually mounted file system. Use a "real" disk (i.e. a disk image), format that as fat and use `imgmount` to moutn that. Then you have a chance of being able to interact with the underlying block storage from within dosbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is using the BIOS.ReadSectors function 02h (`int 13h`) with drive number 02h. All BIOS drive numbers that don't have their 8th bit set refer to floppy drives. So you were actually requesting access to the third floppy drive on the system. Certainly not the DOSBox mounted C: drive.
Additionally, the functions on BIOS `int 13h` deal with the disk as a **physical** entity, whereas the `c:\users\user\folder` directory that DOSBox mounted for you became the **logical** C: drive.
DOS allows you to approach your logical drives on the sector level using `int 25h` (read) and `int 26h` (write). See http://www.techhelpmanual.com/565-int_25h_26h__absolute_disk_read_write.html

I have tried to use the DOS.AbsoluteDiskRead `int 25h` with DOS drive number 2 for C:, but DOSBox does not return anything, not even a carry flag for success or failure. Frankly, I did not think that it would work, especially knowing that the creators of DOSBox have repeatedly said their emulator should only be able to run old DOS games and nothing more. Maybe that the derivative work [DOSBox-X](https://dosbox-x.com/) does it better?